# Team description not showing

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

I created a team, added URL's and saved changes, *and then* edited the page to have a description. ...twice. [The edits seem to be in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/189/rubberduck?tab=History), but my team page still says "*This team has not provided a description yet.*"

Blame caching?

Comment: If this is blamed on caching then every next bug can be blamed on that as well....

Answer (score 2):

I made another edit - removed some whitespace from the end of the post and it looks like it is showing up again.

I did note that there was an empty revision (by Rubberduck) in the revision list - that was the last one and it looks like that's was causing the issue.

Comment: Looks like you have another case [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315960/should-newly-created-stackoverflow-teams-be-available-for-use-immediately)...