# Should newly created Stack Overflow Teams be available for use immediately?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, old-teams

Having read [The Teams Private Beta is Starting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309716/42473) I creating my first team yesterday.

Although I added a description, I see that today my [Teams page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/228/diamond-developers) shows:

> **About Diamond Developers**
>
> This team has not provided a description yet.

Since the same problem was described in [Team description not showing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315299/team-description-not-showing) and given the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, I wonder if this is a different problem.

Looking at the Team page, I can't see how you can submit team questions (I tried doing the obvious thing, but it just posted a, now deleted, [question on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35134965/42473)). See also my followup question: [Does Teams support Team Q&A, and if not, will it ever support it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316102/42473)

So, do new Teams have to be authorised in any way, or do their descriptions or team members need to be audited before a Team becomes accessible?

---

Steps to reproduce the *missing description* problem:

1. Create a Teams page as a recent Teams beta invitee, adding a tagline and logo.
2. Go to the new *Team page* (team name, tagline, and first member appear as expected), see that *This team has not provided a description yet.*
3. Go to the *Edit content and settings* page, and add a description in the *About [team name]* section.
4. *Save Edits* to return to the *Team page* to see that the *About* section is still saying *This team has not provided a description yet.*

It is interesting to note that although this was supposedly [fixed back in January](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315299/team-description-not-showing) and [that Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/189/rubberduck) does have a populated *About* section, no Team created since has. Now while it is possible that my Team is the only one with a description, I think that's unlikely.

Comment: Caching... has to be!

Comment: If I recall correctly, they're still considering the "ask Teams questions" part, and that's not currently implemented or guaranteed to be implemented. So as to how to do that... It doesn't currently exist. (I'll try to find the reference for that.) Edit: [Found what I was thinking of.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions) Scroll down to the "How is Team Q&A going to work?" section of the post.

Comment: Thanks @Kendra I have created a [follow-up question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316102/42473).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found a bug in the save method that was preventing the description from being updated.  A fix has rolled out and should be available now.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, I have just saved a minimal edit, and our Team description is now showing correctly.