# Does Teams support Team Q&A, and if not, will it ever support it?

Tags: discussion, old-teams

It was suggested in a comment to my meta question [Should newly created Stack Overflow Teams be available for use immediately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315960/42473) that Team Q&A had not been implemented yet, and that it might not be, referencing
[The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308601/42473), the section *How is Team Q&A going to work?* says:

> Team Q&A wasn’t going to be a part of the beta (we hoped to ship it in Q1 next year), so we have time to revisit and perhaps rethink it (maybe with an emphasis around product and end-user support). In hindsight, we probably should have made that clearer in the initial announcement.
>
> Team Q&A may be complex enough to deserve its own beta. We’ll return to meta when we have thought through some of the issues surrounding it. Once again, thank you for highlighting the issues we need to explore further.

It isn't clear if that means no Q&A ever, no Q&A in beta or no Q&A before Q1.

Looking at the more recent [The Teams Private Beta is Starting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309716/42473) there is no indication either way on whether Q&A would or wouldn't be included. Indeed, if all that can be contributed to a Teams page is that team description, then it seems pretty pointless.

For us, the decision about how to do internal Q&A was a complicated one, when Teams was offered, I jumped at the chance as it seemed to fit our use case perfectly. Jira and Confluence don't work well for internal Q&A, we don't want to pollute stackoverflow with questions which would only be of interest to a very limited number of people (even though we often work on open source projects), and we don't want to mess about managing our own internal copy of [Askbot](https://askbot.com/) or [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/). As developers we know how well stackoverflow works, and why it is better than other options, so it is a shame that Teams seems to be turning into something less useful.

---

So, has the Q&A functionality been implemented? Is it likely to be implemented? And if we aren't going to get Team Q&A out of Teams, what will Teams actually be used for?

Comment: No, team Q&A is not implemented yet. Yes, it is planned to be implemented. This will probably happen [in 6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) .

Comment: Thanks @TinyGiant, weren't those posts I referenced about [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ago...

Comment: It will be implemented some time between now and then.

Comment: Great follow-up. I'm sure a dev will stop in with full clarifications later, but it does look like I mis-remembered whether it might or might not be implemented. It does read like they still intend to implement this, just not yet.

Answer (score 12):

So the quick answers first and then I'll expand a bit:

> [H]as the Q&A functionality been implemented?

No. Not yet.

> Is it likely to be implemented?

It is still something we plan on exploring.

> And if we aren't going to get Team Q&A out of Teams, what will Teams actually be used for?

We're figuring this out still.

---

Now the long answer:

When we presented the idea of Team Q&A originally, we had a sketchy idea of what Team Q&A could look like: namely a way for people to ask questions specifically to a team and *only* those team members could answer it. To be honest, this idea still sounds interesting to me at a big picture level. However the community did a great job of pointing out some of potential problems this approach could have, such as:

- This will create highly specific questions that only a few handful of people anywhere in the world could answer. This seems to go against the SO-model of the content is king—not the person.
- With only a small subset of people available to answer, these people may be too busy (or don't care enough to answer them), which could lead to a lot of unanswered questions. More unanswered questions could lead to a ghost-town feeling, which could exacerbate the problem further.
- The community has a hard enough time keeping questions on-topic. This would seemingly open up a pandora's box that *could* spill over into the community. Is this question on-topic in a Team but off-topic in the community? Says who? People already argue over what is exactly off-topic. This would only amplify the issue.
- Who would moderate these questions? Our moderators do an amazing job, but this could exponentially increase their workload for potentially little gain to SO.
- Would this fracture SO Q&A into a million mini-SOs on SO?
- How would we keep moderation consistent across every.single.team?

These problems aren't insurmountable, but the solutions aren't easy or self-evident either. So instead of forging ahead with an idea that had a number of flags raised over it, the Team… team has been taking a step back and asking ourselves: what do we like about the Team Q&A concept? What don't we like? How could we achieve those positive results without hurting Q&A?

Which brings us to your last question about what Teams will be used for. We have a few ideas, but we're interested in how people use Teams first before we commit too much in any specific direction. If you have an idea for Teams, **please share it!** We'd love to hear how people would like to use Teams.

Internally we have a couple ideas for Teams that we'll be bringing to the Meta community soon. We're excited about these ideas, but we want to make sure we do a better job of including the community in the process, allowing you—the community—to have a chance to influence and shape these ideas as well.

Comment: Thanks for being sincere, could you please ask a new meta SO question canvassing for ideas?

Comment: @DeerHunter Sure! I have a few posts to write this month, but I'll make sure this gets out there as well. :)

Comment: Thanks @Hynes, it's great to see an internal perspective. While I appreciate that you have to take a step back given the shockingly negative response, I think the proof of the pudding is in the eating. Until we can try out Team Q&A, we won't find out which of these potential problems are actual problems. Personally, I think setting Privileges at beta site levels inside Teams (so a 2k so user would have mod privs on team questions) would solve most of the moderation problems. Also, we would need it to be easy to move between Teams & SO, so Close, should be on SO & Close, should be on Team etc.

Comment: @DeerHunter Was something like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316135/42473) what you were thinking?

Comment: @MarkBooth - yes, thank you. Noted and upvoted, FWIW.