# What do we want out of teams and how could we make it work?

Tags: discussion, old-teams

When the idea of Teams was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307513/42473), many people were cynical and very negative about the idea of Team Q&A. That negativity continued in the wake of [clarification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308601/42473) and even in the [beta announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309716/42473) it looked like Team Q&A was being shelved.

Fast forward a few months and I finally get my Teams Beta invitation, but the excitement quickly dulled when I realised that Teams wasn't quite what I'd been sold back in October.

Since it [now looks like we are going to have to wait for Team Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316111/42473) I would like to explore what people want out of Teams, what your use cases are and how we avoid all of the problems raised by previous discussions on the subject.

Comment: If only they'd asked this first...

Comment: It's very effective in terms of Search Engine visibility. Looking for my team's name on Google right now displays our Stack Overflow Teams page as the first result

Comment: "What do we want out of teams"? I personally want it to disappear...

Comment: Well it looks like you already have your wish @l4mpi as Teams is currently has no Team Q&A functionality. I have to ask though, why do you onject to other people making use of a facility you don't want? How would the use of Teams Q&A by people who want it, affect the way you use Stack Overflow? Finally, are you sure there are there no solutions to whatever objections you have? That is, after all, the point of this question.

Comment: @Mark my main objection is against turning SO into anything else than a high quality knowledge repository. But it's probably far too late for that; the profile rework, #SOReadyToHelp and Teams all deviate from that idea and stray dangerously into social network territory. As for Teams Q/A, I simply don't think that posting a question to a fixed group of people has any place on SO (one of SOs core principles is that anybody who knows the right answer can post it). And philosophical differences aside, I highly doubt the benefits would outweight all the issues with moderation, fragmentation, etc.

Comment: @MarkBooth: The "don't like it, don't use it" argument really doesn't apply to Team Q&A. The reason many of us (myself included) are against Team Q&A are the detrimental effects we see it having on the *main site*. I think those discussions have been had in more depth in other places, so I won't repeat them here, but that's our complaint.

Comment: @MarkBooth: I am also personally of the opinion that the questions that Team Q&A would allow are fundamentally worthless, however, I could easily be convinced otherwise if someone would actually present some good examples.

Comment: @Linuxios good examples would be exceptionally good. I've read through this (and the others) a few times, and I really don't quite get what it is going to provide apart from a way to say 'hey world, I work with him, and her, and the thing we keep in the corner oh and when we're really bored we do a bit of stuff on x project' WHAT IS THE PROBLEM THIS SOLVES FOR ME!

Comment: @Michael B: Exactly.

Comment: I remember reading through the documentation project description, and thinking 'that's a really good idea, that actually could solve the really big problem of crap documentation - I'm genuinely looking forward to it happening. Then I read about teams, and thought 'eh' - Teams without Q&A (this is an SE thing right - how can it not have Q&A!) I really really don't get how it benefits anyone.

Comment: That's what I think you are missing @Linuxios, there are a class of question which are worthless to the main site, but could be invaluable within a Team, and indeed that only the Team could answer. If I asked to you "How do I configure an NXDetector for multiple ContinuousVelocityMotionControllers?" you would have no idea what I was talking about, but it is a practical, answerable problem based on an actual problem I have faced, and some members of my team would be able to answer it, probably the only people able. If the question were answerable on Stack Overflow, I would ask it there.

Comment: @MarkBooth: But if these questions are applicable only to those within a team, how is this a class of questions we *want* to cater to on SO? This isn't some kind of public Slack channel.

Comment: Apart from a very narrow view, my example question is a perfectly valid Stack Overflow question - we no longer have a "Too Localized" close reason. Plenty of questions already sit languishing in no answer/no vote territory, encouraging questions which are unlikely to be answerable or interesting to an appropriate Teams site will only improve the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as can no longer be reproduced because this is from the old Teams product which was [un-shipped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330427/6471538) in August 2016.

Answer (score 11):

## Why was I excited by the idea of Teams?

As I said in my question [Does Teams support Team Q&A, and if not, will it ever support it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316102/42473) :

> For us, the decision about how to do internal Q&A was a complicated one, when Teams was offered, I jumped at the chance as it seemed to fit our use case perfectly. Jira and Confluence don't work well for internal Q&A, we don't want to pollute stackoverflow with questions which would only be of interest to a very limited number of people (even though we often work on open source projects), and we don't want to mess about managing our own internal copy of [Askbot](https://askbot.com/) or [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/). As developers we know how well stackoverflow works, and why it is better than other options, so it is a shame that Teams seems to be turning into something less useful.

So the important thing to me is that I want people to be able to ask very Team-specific questions, even on our open source projects, and not have it pop up on peoples list of new questions and them thinking "How do we close this now we no longer have a *Too localised* close reason?".

This boils down to,

- Use case: As a software developer, I want to feel free to ask questions which wouldn't be interesting to the wider Stack Overflow community.

In addition,

- Use case: As a software developer, I want to be able to easily ask, answer and find answers to Team-specific questions.
- Use case: As a software developer, I want to be able to ask, answer and search Team-specific questions using the effective, efficient Stack Overflow system that I already know.
- Use case: As a Stack Exchange advocate, I want to encourage developers who don't currently engage with Stack Overflow to become full members of the community<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>* I know it's difficult to believe, but some developers just use Stack Overflow to find answers, without ever asking questions, voting or gaining reputation points!</sup>

## Suggestions

### Team Q&A

While I understand many of the concerns about Team Q&A, I feel the only way to find out whether a concern is real or just imagined is to try out Team Q&A in a limited form. But this sounds like a lot of work to try it out and then possibly abandon it or change it substantially in light of experience. So,

#### Preview Teams Q&A using team tags to filter the standard Stack Overflow

Rather than building out a complete new system for Team questions, a tag based proto-team system could be considered. In this proposal, questions with the team-tag would be hidden from everyone except Team members (just like ignored tags with the hide option), while being highlighted for Team members.

This also has the advantage that, while we are finding out how this works, switching a question between a Team and the main site would be as easy as adding or removing a tag. Also, this reminds people that Teams questions aren't really private; they just aren't as easily accessible as non-Teams questions. They would still show up on searches for instance.

### Moderation issues

Understandably, concerns have been raised over the moderation of Team Q&A. So,

#### Use beta privileges for Team questions

Rather than relying on moderation from the whole Stack Overflow community, keep the burden within the Team as far as possible.

Since a Team is much smaller than the community, using the privilege levels of beta sites for Team questions would help a lot. 2k members would have moderator privileges on Team questions and members with just 500 rep. would be able to cast close and reopen votes. This should bring moderator tools within the grasp of many potential Teams. With experienced Stack Overflow members comes the knowledge of what good questions look like and how to deal with improving poor questions, so I think this could solve most of the moderation problems.

### Fragmentation issues

In many respects, I saw the aim of Teams as promoting a limited form of fragmentation. I don't want the main site distracted by handling my Teams very localised application-specific questions.

I think that the important thing here is that it should be easy to 'promote' a Teams question up to the main site. We will get people asking what they think is a Team specific question, only to realise the solution is more general and widely applicable, so we need it to be easy for that question to make the transition.

### Team abuse

Another concern people expressed was the use of Teams to create anarchic enclaves where the normal rules don't apply. Again, as long as these don't spill out onto the main site, I don't see a problem. Eventually someone will flag them and they will get removed.

More of a problem would be groups of new Stack Overflow members creating Teams and using them without really knowing how Stack Overflow works (or how to get the most out of it), people spamming the Teams system with frivolous Teams, or those who would create new Stack Overflow accounts to bypass any max. Teams per person limit.

I think this could be mitigated by having to have a certain rep before being able to create Teams, and/or having to have at least one sponsor with close privileges or better, who can act as pseudo moderator and set people on the right track.

## Conclusion

Ultimately, I think that Teams has the potential to provide new Q&A workflows which complement existing uses of Stack Overflow and encourage developers who are currently skirting the edges of our community to fully commit to it.

There may be rough edges which need smoothing off, but I can see value in these ideas and hope others can too.

Comment: +1. I think it would be nice to have the Team Q&A, and for sorting, it might do very well to have a sub-domain for each team Q&A, eg [teamName].teams.SO.com etc.  Almost a mini SE site.

Comment: Given that multiple teams can have the same name, I suspect that `[numericTeamId].stackoverflow.com` would be more likely. *8')

Comment: That'd be fine as well (although not quite as nice IMO); Point being a mini SE site for your team.  Maybe when it got to be big enough (if it did), it could be migrated to a full-blown SE site (kinda like going through Area 51...)

Comment: I ask myself the whole time: Couldn't one just by smart filtering achieve the same kind of specialization/localization with only a minimum of fragmentation? What are the advantages of Team specific hideaways for questions when they just could be tagged accordingly? After all one cannot assume that all available experts are in a team. This might be bad. So I would be primarily concerned about the negative sides of fragmentation and I would prefer better tagging and filtering mechanisms instead.

Comment: @Trilarion - I attempted to address your issues in [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316425).

Answer (score 3):

## Fragmentation vs. community building

1. Stack Overflow has about 4700-4800 [experts actively answering questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342741). This is way above [Dunbar's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_Number) and induces alienation and natural fragmentation of the community.
2. Teams (5-10 members) are too small to build a strong sense of belonging to SO in general. While they can be useful in guerrilla warfare, tactical combat, and software development, the concept is unsuitable for answering questions (burden-sharing becomes an issue and the law of large numbers cannot guarantee continuous availability).
3. Multiple hattips to Christopher Alexander and his [Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pattern_Language). Solution: formalize existing language **tag communities** which are mostly the [right size](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/342649/number-of-active-experts-per-week-in-a-tag-so-parameterized).
4. #### Let's call tag communities 'Town Halls' (or 'Tag Halls', 'Guild Halls'):

   - Membership in Tag Halls is granted automatically to any user who has answered (with positive score) two or more questions **from users not belonging to the Hall** in the previous week, and is revoked if this condition isn't fulfilled
   - A Tag Hall has its own chat room (yes, this already exists), and a (publicly readable, member-writable) discussion forum where **only tag-relevant stuff can be discussed (no chit-chat)**  .
   - There's no need in extra moderation privileges.
   - **IMPORTANT** Each Tag Hall has its own, colorful membership badges designed by members (so no pressure on SE graphics team here), and perhaps other visual fluff - badges should be displayed on member's profiles.
   - Tag Halls can have their own wiki pages with links to external resources. An old link is automatically pushed down and then evicted from the page.
5. Hat tip to [@Trilarion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1536976/trilarion)'s [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316135/what-do-we-want-out-of-teams-and-how-could-we-make-it-work#comment305072_316425): smaller tags (e.g. up to 10 active members) can still have **Tag Teams**. Tags with (say) from 10 to 50 members will have **Tag Villages**, and anything larger will be called **Tag Halls**. The idea is to gamify community building and regularly answering questions from random outsiders.

Comment: Thanks, I too like the idea of using tags. I suggested it as an prototyping system, but if it works well enough I don't see any reason why it couldn't just be left like that permanently.

Comment: This idea sounds really good. Build communities around tags. I really like it. Btw. for less frequent tags this might just melt with Teams: 'Tag Teams'.

Comment: @Trilarion - there can be a certain progression, depending on size - Tag Team, Tag Village, Tag Hall or sth. like that.

Comment: @Trilarion - have edited this into the answer.

Comment: @DeerHunter Thanks for taking the time to share your idea. These are the types of suggestions we love to hear! While Teams doesn't currently have all the items in place that you suggested, we would definitely welcome teams forming around tags. People could use Teams for various reasons (tags, companies, open-source projects, student groups), and as we see more similar teams form, we will build features which support those teams.