# What team member SO Activity should we gather and show on Teams?

Tags: discussion, old-teams

For those who don't know me, I'm a product designer at **Stack Overflow**, working on the *Teams* product. If you need a background on Teams, [read this awesome post from Tim.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better)

We're at a point with Teams where can begin exploring different content ideas, and I wanted to share one idea with you: **Team Stack Overflow Activity.** The idea is to show a team's collective Stack Overflow activity (Questions and Documentation), allowing people to see how *this team* engages with Stack Overflow. This can help give a fuller picture of not only what the team *says* they're interested in, but also *show* how they are contributing to Stack Overflow (and the world's developer knowledge). It could also provide an encouragement for team members to get involved with Stack Overflow.

What type of information would we gather? Some initial ideas are listed below. These aren't exhaustive and all are open for discussion.

- Team Reputation (Daily, Weekly, Quarterly, Total, and/or Total?)
- Team Badge Count (Total)
- Top posts made by the team ([Time Period]? All-time?)
- Top tags the team posts in ([Time Period]? All-time?)
- Recent post activity
- Recent badge(s) earned
- Rarest badge earned
- Favorited Questions
- <s>Voting activity</s> *[see Andy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316257/91687)*
- *Your suggestion??*

At this point we have no implementation plans. We haven't written a spec yet, designed any screens, or built a prototype. Before we started any of that, we first wanted to pitch the idea to you and hear what you thought. Does this interest you? What would you change? What would you add **or remove** from the list above?

> ### Interested in joining the Teams Private Beta?
>
> You don't have to wait for public beta to get involved. [Sign-up if you're interested!](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1CpgNiGZ0XNUqueXc4dydraliKZqZnJO7HWEuesXYkmQ/viewform?usp=send_form)
>
> ---
>
> ### Have a different idea for Teams?
>
> We'd love to hear it! Either create a new post, tagged with [teams](/questions/tagged/teams) or [join the discussion here: "What do we want out of teams and how could we make it work?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316135/what-do-we-want-out-of-teams-and-how-could-we-make-it-work)

Comment: I can't help but look at this from the point of view of a moderator. Case in point: "Voting activity" is the first thing I notice in that list...

Comment: @BoltClock Can you expand what you mean by that?

Comment: Well, when you've been a moderator for long enough, eventually you'll start suspecting everyone :(

Comment: @BoltClock Ah. Well the idea with "Voting Activity" was showing what questions / answers people on the team are upvoting. I'm not sure that's interesting, but it's an idea. :)

Comment: @Hynes Concerning showing what people on the team are upvoting, I assume you're not going to say _who_ upvoted it. Assuming that... What about teams with only one person, since that's allowed? Wouldn't that be revealing voting data at that point? With only two members, you could theoretically guess who upvoted what with a 50% chance of being right.

Comment: @Kendra All great points. We don't want to reveal voting history so I don't think we would reveal _who_ voted. Just that someone did. Again, maybe that's too big of a privacy concern. Also for teams that have only one member, I'm not 100% sure we'd do this for them. They already have a profile and this seems like a repeat of the same data.

Comment: @Hynes Sounds like I expected, just wanted to make sure this was taken into consideration. :) Otherwise, I like the look of this so far.

Comment: @Hynes Is there a [teams] FAQ? I have searched a lot for that. If not, I will add it as a suggestion (in the form of an answer).

Comment: @BhargavRao Not yet. Please provide an answer so we answer questions you (and others) might have.

Comment: @Hynes Added the answer. Also can you make this [featured]? This concerns a lot more users than the normal meta crowd.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've featured the post and updated the title to be a bit more descriptive. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a disservice both to the team and to its members. I can't think of any reason why someones *personal* Stack Overflow activity has any bearing on what their *team* works on. Someone might be working on a team building iOS apps, and still not be active in the [ios] tag. I think that this feature would tie individual activity far to closely to the team.

Comment: @Linuxios Because it could show that while a team might be building iOS apps, their team members don't focus on that, but are involved in other items. It's an attempt to fill in a picture of "what is this team interested in" even if it's not what they work in every day. Again, it's an idea. :)

Comment: @Hynes: Definitely, and I'm very glad you brought it to Meta for discussion. I guess my question is really this: is a Team more about the team, and what they have accomplished as a group, or about a collection of people, and what those people do? If the former, this seems misplaced, if the later, then I misunderstood Teams (and I personally believe the later to be a useless and harmful feature, though I could be convinced otherwise in time :) ).

Comment: I don't think any of the gamification metrics make sense for Teams, as I understand them.  Companies (hopefully) have something better to brag about than imaginary Internet points.  I suppose teams that are just groups of friends might want to compete against other groups of friends, but I personally think that kind of points-for-points-sake behavior is bad for the site overall.  I think it'd be better for teams to feature Q&A they liked (theirs or others'), especially for companies wanting to support products.

Comment: *Interested in joining the Teams Private Beta?* - I am still waiting for docs beta, so why we jumping onto other train before we get done with the first one?

Comment: @Mr.Alien https://docs-beta.stackexchange.com, started for a few tags already.

Comment: @BhargavRao Docs is currently in beta, but it's a closed beta so you have to receive an email with an invitation code in order to join. The team working on Docs has been inviting people in waves; there are still people who signed up that haven't gotten in yet because we didn't just invite everyone all at once. That link won't work for people who haven't already been invited and logged in.

Comment: @Laura Yep, True. I am still waiting for the [python] tag to start and the mail. Too bad that you guys started out from the .NET Side :-( http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAFyh.png

Comment: There should be absolutely no display of team reputation, voting activity, badge hunts etc. All of that will certainly result in private voting circles, cliques and bandwagon-voting.

Comment: @Lundin Badge hunts?

Comment: @Mr.Alien We've been running concurrent private betas for a while. So far we haven't experienced any issues gaining interest in either.

Comment: On the subject of teams with one person... shouldn't that very scenario be disallowed in the first place. The whole notion of a *team* is a group of multiple people. So if you create a team it should probably be "in hiatus" or "hidden"/"inactive" until at least one other person joins it. That would not only make sense on its own, it would also help to solve the issue of privacy concerns for "Team Activity".

Comment: @TylerH We've been hesitant about setting a member floor to qualify teams until we have a better idea of how many people join teams. It's a good suggestion. Can you make this it's own post?

Comment: @Hynes will do.

Comment: @Hynes http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316447/make-teams-require-multiple-people

Comment: @Lundin: Excellent point.

Comment: @Hynes - here's [another take](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316425) on the Teams. TL;DR: Teams have to be aligned with tags and have to be gamified to promote answering questions in the tag.

Answer (score 81):

I don't know how to express this in a positive way, and I want to, but, the *Teams* feature is more and more looking like a solution in search of a problem; the "we built a thing, please tell us what features you want, our developers have free time" is a creative product management approach.

The [5 largest *Teams* (by membership)](https://stackoverflow.com/teams?tab=members) consist of 4 companies using it for marketing purposes and the [SOPython "community" group](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/50/sopython-community) that was created because we (your tireless [SOPython](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/5/sopython) tag/chat janitors), had concerns that the permissions model allows an arbitrary user to change the publicly-displayed content on the *Teams* pages.

If I was a company looking to hire and I wanted to say "look at the brilliant dudes/dudettes that you'd be working with," then I could maybe see the point of creating a *Team*.  But that said, if I was a company that wanted to create a *Team* page, I would have already created a [*Company* page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-overflow).  Which means that I'd be creating a *Team* page to squat the namespace to protect my company image (e.g. someone grabbing team/RedHat and then using that platform to talk about business models that are vampiric on the open-source community).  Hooray.

Where the *Teams* feature is open for both businesses and user-groups, I have to ask: was this created in mind as a platform to support recruiting and marketing?  Was some market-testing done and you found people would pay for this?  *Teams* as a "hello fellow developer" company-image platform with a side of passive candidate lead-generation makes sense.  If this is a monetization thing that you need to support the core Q/A economy, I'll get it -- it's just you and me here, you can tell me.

If teams is here to stay, due to sunk cost or because it's an executive's favorite pet, my suggestion would be linking *Company* and *Team* pages.  There's a lot of overlap anyway (showcasing/marketing open source contributions, achievements of team members, suggestion of expertise) and it would solve some of your content-problems.

Comment: +1 It does feel like a somewhat unnecessary feature.

Comment: I have also been having these thoughts as having signed up for the beta and aforementioned SOPython group and have yet to see anything useful. One could also argue for groups that this seems like a redundant copy of [their group or community page](http://sopython.com/)

Comment: Personally I only think Teams makes sense if there is no commercial interest in them at all. That's the _only_ way you can keep crap like marketing and company restrictions on individual users away from the site.

Comment: We should do a separate post explaining more where we're going, I guess. To briefly answer here: (a) Yes, *the* major motivator for teams is to integrate with careers and company pages and help developers find jobs, and we're already working on that integration (b) We don't want to *limit* it to just being for companies hiring devs, we want it to be open to open source projects, community teams, etc., which is why we're leaving it open-ended. I'm actually pretty interested in the teams that people are creating that *aren't* companies.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: you definitely need to do another post to adequately explain the goal of teams; every time I read (another) post about it I feel like you guys don't know what you're doing, or should be doing (this question being 'evidence' of that) and therefore it's a pet project solution looking for a problem, *or* that we're being chivvied along into a feature that (admittedly arguably) we don't really want. Or need. I'm willing to accept this is my lack of understanding of the intent, but nothing so far has convinced me of the use, purpose or value of this feature.

Answer (score 76):

This isn't a feature, but a concern. Voting history may not be a good idea. You've already mentioned the problem with 1 team member.

What about 2? I know *I* didn't vote on that question, so I know who did.

There are also questions that are outside of our "normal" area of influence, but one member is known to follow that area. I have a pretty good idea who voted on that question now.

I think showing anything other than "Total Up/Downvotes" is going to be to easy to identify which team members are voting where - especially on small teams. Quickly paging through the Teams listings, it looks like a large majority of teams have 5 or fewer members. That is going to make identifying who is voting on what fairly simple.

The other point about exactly what the team is voting on, is a mini-meta effect. If I see two of my team members read and voted on a question, I may wander over to see what that question is about. Rinse and repeat across a handful of questions and suddenly, everywhere a team visits there are 3 more up votes.

Comment: Fair enough. The answer may be we don't show anything involving voting activity (at least for now—we can always revisit this again in the future if we want to).

Comment: +1 -- confidentiality of voting is pretty critical to the SE system in general. It allows for quality control, and allows people to be involved in the site without getting engaged in discussions and arguments if they don't want to.

Comment: I think this answer makes a very good point with regards to small teams. Perhaps voting shouldn't be included at all. To be honest, I am not really interested in who is voting where, and that in many ways is the way voting was designed as well.

Comment: @Hynes How about displaying votes for tags rather than questions? For example you can say "Team X has 500 upvotes for Tag1", maybe also limit it to tags with more than, say, 50 questions to ensure there's no privacy concerns.

Comment: What about making it a per-team setting? I my team wants to let everyone know, why not? I know I personally wouldn't mind. Or maybe only enabling this for "big" teams.

Answer (score 33):

I like this a lot. One idea:

**Highlight questions that are *unanswered* (no accepted answer) by team members, in addition to top or recent ones.**

And if they're ASKING questions and need help, the people following are likely to be especially excited to be able to help a colleague or provide a solution to a team they're a fan of.

Comment: Wouldn't this encourage targeted voting? Colleagues voting for questions posted by their co-workers is a major source of invalid voting.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense if the team consists of colleagues working for the same company. Why does the person have to make post on an internet site to get an answer by their own team members? Why can't they just ask them IRL? They would get a faster answer, better answer and with less misunderstandings.

Comment: @Lundin, not per se. If it's a big company, maybe you wouldn't know who to go to. We've got over 100 developers here, and yet I sometimes ask a question on Stack Overflow without consulting each of them first...

Comment: @GolezTrol Regardless, I don't think it should be Stack Overflow's mission to fix broken internal communication in dysfunctional mega corporations. Also if there are 100 developers, what makes you think you're in the team with the person who can answer the question? You might be in the "Fizz project team" and the programming guru who can answer the question and sits in the office next to you might be in the "Buzz project team". Also who do you think said guru cares most about to help, a person showing up IRL and humbly asking for help, or some random, anonymous internet person?

Comment: Well, actually i'm in the "Bazinga! team" at work, but we only have one SO team for the company. :p -  Anyway, maybe you should focus more on the part that says *"..or provide a solution to a team they're a fan of"*, and let others decide whether they see it as an additional benefit that those fans might possibly be team members too.

Answer (score 28):

What about Teams who don't interact with SO much, but prefer [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)? We perform most of our reviews there. Heck, our project even [has a tag for the purpose](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubberduck).

Or, thinking bigger, what about people who don't really use SO, but prefer Programmers? Is that activity somehow not worth seeing?

Not every body on a Team Project is an active SO member. It would be great if we could display other Stack Exchange activity from SE network sites outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not worth seeing. It sounds like you're suggesting that team member activity be allowed from other SE network sites, _not_ just Stack Overflow. Is that correct?

Comment: Precisely @Hynes. Not everyone is an active SO member.

Comment: Cool. I would suggest editing your post to suggest that (and it's a great idea!). Thanks for taking the time to suggest it.

Comment: You're welcome @Hynes. I gave it a shot at clarifying my intention.

Comment: That's a logical expansion of the proposal.  Great idea.

Comment: It was my understanding that Stack Overflow Teams was for the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: @TylerH StackExchange is a big place. There are *lots* of programming related sites outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm aware. Yet, the point remains that Teams is under the Stack Overflow domain.

Comment: So what @TylerH? I fail to see your point. Give me a good reason why this other SE activity *shouldn't* be included. Convince me.

Comment: @RubberDuck The onus is not with me to convince you that a Stack Overflow feature should not be added to non-Stack Overflow sites. I'm not even arguing that. I'm only saying it's a Stack Overflow-specific feature. If you want Teams on non-SO sites, you should make a feature request for that with a supporting argument for it. This post and its associated feature are about the Stack Overflow site, specifically.

Comment: My argument isn't that this "feature" be added to other sites, but that this isn't a stack overflow feature to begin with. It's rightfully a Stack *Exchange* feature that happens to be hosted on SO.

Comment: As an aside @TylerH. This attitude of yours is pervasive in the SO community and a big reason many of us *don't* actively participate.

Comment: @RubberDuck What attitude? I've simply pointed out that your post is in the wrong place. Also I'd hardly say a user with several thousand rep isn't actively participating. Your personal attack is not constructive, please stick to the topics at hand.

Answer (score 21):

The [Teams Page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) is [missing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/teams-so-activity-a-content-idea?noredirect=1#comment303591_316245) a [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ).

Everyone who is new to anypage will first ask the question - ***Where's The FAQ?***

I suggest that we add a FAQ for the page first.

Comment: Good idea!  But I'm not sure it really responds to the post?  There're lots of other things we can and should add, but this one seems more about how you'd improve *this* feature?

Comment: @Jaydles Yep, True. I asked Hynes in a comment above if I can [add an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/teams-so-activity-a-content-idea#comment303588_316245). Also Adding a FAQ certainly improves any content. It helps a lot for the general public to learn about the feature (Isn't that a bigger improvement?)

Answer (score 10):

I would love to see (maybe a team voted?) favorite personal github repos

For example, lots of us on the JavaScript team love making cool gists, codepens, canvas, or even just games. So a team Repo of the [Week, Month?] would be pretty cool.

Comment: "The JavaScript Team"? Out of curiosity, what is that?

Comment: @Linuxios http://stackoverflow.com/teams/57/javascript only the 6th best team on SO!

Comment: @SterlingArcher looks like 57th to me

Comment: Not according to member quantity!

Answer (score 9):

As [member of the Team Git](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/112/git), I would also like to display links to external articles / release announcements around the software I and my colleague support.

The possibility to even publish some some article/blog post within the team space would be equally interesting.

Comment: Interesting. And not just articles. Links to the website of your product, team or company, links to other profile pages of your team, and for companies the possibility to link to the company site *and* the StackCareers website would be interesting.

Answer (score 8):

I would be interested in seeing aggregate activity for the following subjects:

- Number of votes cast (I'm not interested in *what* they voted on so much as how many votes were cast)
- Number of helpful flags
- Number of people reached
- Number of posts edited

It would be great to see "okay, this team of 10 users has reached a collective of 2 million people, wow". Or "This team is really active on the site; together they've edited 20,000 posts!" That would be a great indicator at a glance of the contributions of a team.

Thinking from the POV of the only team I'm in, [SOCVR](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/11/socvr), that's really some of the most pertinent team data I can think of.

Comment: I would expand the votes to see total number of upvotes, downvotes, close votes, reopen votes, and delete votes, as well as include the number of declined / disputed flags (just to make it an accurate representation)

Comment: A BIG +1 for "People Reached" and "Edits".  Love highlighting those as ways team members are serving the dev/SO community beyond just posts.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a suggestion, so much as a concern - be very careful in showing aggregated team contributions in an easy to find place. Even "recent post activity from those on the team."

It would be very easy to accidentally encourage improper voting activity by making it simple to see all the posts from those on your team (like a feed?). This would be made even worse if people from the same team are sharing an IP due to work, etc.

It might seem harmless to upvote that content, as you read it, but doing so would very quickly create voting patterns and raise suspicion. Sorting out "legitimate" teams from "voting fraud" teams would be nearly impossible.

Comment: How would showing recent post activity encourage improper voting activity?  I can already view the newest votes for individuals and engage in the same behavior you are already describing. To my knowledge, this activity isn't happen currently. I'm not saying it couldn't happen, but I'm also pointing out you could this already if you wanted to. I'm not disregarding your comment. I'm trying to understand more fully how you see this happening (because I don't improper voting activity either.) :)

Comment: @Hynes well yeah. But where on SO can I view a feed of all posts from all my coworkers, in a single place, that I likely would be interested in reading and want to vote? I could go to each person's page individually, on a daily basis, but.. that's a lot higher barrier to voting fraud than an updated listing of all their posts.

Comment: There is a user RSS feed available for every user. [Here's yours.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/1048539) [Here's mine.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/2640230)

Comment: @Hynes that's not the point. The point is having an easy to access location to easily view all my coworkers posts _without me doing anything_ and having that automatically provided to me. It's only natural I would be inclined to upvote them.

Comment: I looked into this a bit back when Teams was first proposed; it'd be trivial to just invalidate all cross-voting between team members, and if this becomes a problem I think that's probably the most equitable solution to it.

Comment: @Shog9: It might be trivial, but it might raise problems with valid votes.

Answer (score 3):

Three things come to mind:

1. How would the rollup stats for Teams work? For instance, if you're showing total team rep, the team of 100 passive users may still trump the team of 3 active users. Would it be a weighted score? Would it be categorized by team size? Would it just a raw tally, regardless of team size? All of the above?
2. Make sure there's a 1-many relationship between users and teams. I might want to be part of my company's team and part of my local usergroup's team.
3. Related badges:

   - "Nepotist": Answer on teammate's question was accepted and received a score of X or more from **non-teammates**. value of X determines bronze/silver/gold
   - "Dwight": Downvoted a teammate's question or answer. Awarded once. Basically a team-"Critic" badge.

Comment: I'm not sure I like your "Dwight" badge idea as much, since it could lead to targeted voting, even if it is downvoting, of teammates to get badges.

Comment: @Kendra I thought about that, but I think the fact that you'd have to do it to a teammate is a deterrent, not to mention that- beyond a clever-ish name- it's not an awesome badge to have (think "peer-pressure", "tumbleweed", etc.) Maybe cut out the bronze/silver/gold for that badge, and award it only once like the "Critic" badge to keep it from getting out of hand.

Comment: But you have to consider that there will be people who create a team, and some of them may make a legit team, a team they are actually part of, for the pure goal of getting that badge. Or they'll talk about it outside of SO and coordinate the downvotes with other actions so that their rep is unaffected. The other one you suggest _at least_ has a non-member factor to regulate it (x score or more from non-teammates) so it can't be gamed _as_ easily.

Comment: @Kendra if the "Critic" badge is a legitimate badge, I think a "Dwight" badge that follows the modifications from my previous comment would meet the threshold as well, since at that point it's just a team-critic badge.

Comment: I stand by it's a _targetted_ badge. Critic isn't asking you to target a person/group of people (depending on the size of the team) but it _is_ less targetting with your modification, I will admit.

Comment: Wouldn't the nepotist badge (in)directly encourage vote-fraud/voting-rings?

Comment: @joelmdev That is exactly the part that would encourage voting rings. There is a higher-than-normal relationship between team members, so having a badge that requires team members to vote you up seems like 1) a circle jerk 2) likely to cause an increase in teams just for the sake of getting a badge 3) not really a worthywhile achievement IMO (because why wouldn't people you share an interest with upvote your answer? It's just like asking coworkers to go upvote your Stack Overflow answer)

Comment: @DavidThomas, I don't think so, because votes from *inside* the team have no bearing on progress towards the badge, so it's just like any other badge that depends on score only *more* restrictive. The only part that is team dependent is the relationship between the asker and answerer.

Comment: @TylerH I mis-spoke in my comment- it was supposed to read "from *inside* the teams". That's how the suggestion in my answer reads, but not my original comment. I just reposted it above with the correction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit afraid of exact voting history, but voting does tell you something about the area of interest of the team members, so maybe the Top Tags for the team can be based not just on posts, but also on activity in general, like comments and votes, or maybe just specify the top 3 tags based on posts and add a couple of extra tags based on those metrics.

But I doubt whether those statistics are representative for the team. For instance, in my daily job I work a lot with Delphi, yet I find myself answering only few Delphi questions. In my private life I like to hobby around with web development, so I'm searching for HTML, CSS and JavaScript knowledge, sometimes asking for it too, and at the same time putting my freshly gained knowledge to use in answering other questions. And the volume of those questions is larger too, so there is more to upvote and to answer. So, I doubt if the top tags on my personal profile are much related to my (company) team.

And even if they were, I wonder what the use is of having this information. I was actually hoping that by now we would get a glance on the first *actual* feature that we as a team could use for our benefit, or that others could use to benefit from our team. I'd like to persuade more collegues to join the team and in some cases even join Stack Overflow in order to do so, but for now I got nothing to persuade them with, and I don't think any of the suggestions in the question are going to make a change in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever you do of these, I would limit it only to teams above a reasonable size - 5 members, perhaps, or even 10.  (No idea how big most teams are.)  That would keep voting records from becoming public by accident, and perhaps keep from having quite as much encouragement to game the system in bad ways in some cases.

Comment: Most teams are around 5 (at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

You have to *ban* the voting circles, instead of *encouraging* them.

This whole "team" thing is the worst idea in the life of the SO, and let me predict: it will cause it to lose its significance on the internet, or maybe even kill it.

*To the downvoters: if this answer won't be deleted, in 2 years I will be here again, and we will see, if your downvote was right or not. Welcome back in the 8th February, 2018. I will be there.*

---

*Extension, 28 Aug, 2017:* At early Aug 2016, the SO Teams was [un-shipped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330427/1783163). On the reasoning, the SE  had more important tasks and didn't have enough programmer resource to do it in time properly.

My current view about teams is already not so vehement - I think, voting circles can work pretty well even without such a catalyzing power. Although simple irrational downvoters cause much more trouble here, in my opinion.

Comment: Strong words, can you back that up with some evidence or are you just speculating?

Comment: @gunr2171 I am just speculating, but I am sure, that time will prove the opinions similar to mine.

Comment: @gunr2171 Btw, *how could I give you evidence for a predicted event in the future?* :-)

Answer (score 1):

This does come down to the duel nature currently shown in teams.
There are *companies*, and then there are *user groups*.

My team is a hacker space team (so the second category).
People (explicitly) joined the team cos they wanted to see how they stacked up against there friends in the space.

So we want to see **leader-boards**, broken down by tag.
So I could tell "Hey, X is the best python question answer-er in our team."

Answer (score 1):

Next will be:

1. Job openings for company
2. Tag skills required for each job
3. Apply for job from Company page
4. Follow company/ or want to be in this company
5. Reviews of company :P
6. Salaries review of company :P
7. Interview Questions of company :P

Will go & merge features of LinkedIn & Glassdoor of company page.

Let's see how it goes in future.

Answer (score -1):

Additionaly to the [top unanswered question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316251/2886003) of the team I am for:

- Top posts made by the team:
  This would allow to see activity of the team, in what they are **working as a team** to make great contributions to the community.
  So I would use just posts edited at least by 3 members (I don't consider a pair pair or a group of 1 a team)

Usually working in a team involves a lot of communication between members, in this direction it would also help to know (if they have any chat room), **how many references/links to questions/answers are in the chat room**. So we could know how engaged with StackExchange are.

Another metric it could be how many question of the tags of the team are visited by the team. So if a small team visits 20% of last month questions of tag x, they are quite active in it, while if they just have seen 0.05% not much.

Comment: Could I know which point do you disagree on @downvoters?