# Make Teams require multiple people

Tags: bug, old-teams

Recently, Hynes posted an RFP (Request For Proposals) on [activity people want to see in Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/what-team-member-so-activity-should-we-gather-and-show-on-teams), and one of the suggestions raised a privacy concern:

> - Voting Activity

Discussions about this revealed to me that a Team can consist of only one member. In my opinion, this seems like an inherent bug; "team", by definition, refers to *more than one*. If a single user is interested in portraying some aspect of their activity or interests, well... they have a profile for that. If they're interested in showing off their individual job performance, well... they have a CV for that, and Stack Overflow Careers.

I [suggested in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/what-team-member-so-activity-should-we-gather-and-show-on-teams#comment304714_316245) that we update Teams to require two people: creating a team is done by one person, but that team should remain hidden and/or "in limbo" until at least one other person accepts an invitation or requests to join it, because a team *by definition* is more than one person.

Comment: What if an Open Source project with two contributors loses one≈? Does the page have to go away/shut down, hiding all the information that was on it? That would seem harsh. What if a project has only one contributor to begin with, but would like to grow (and sees other team-related activity already that makes perfect sense, like, say Q&A)?

Comment: Teams have to start somewhere.

Comment: The idea of showing team's voting activity was less than mediocre; I don't think it will survive the review by the (SE) Team, unless their product design process is in total disarray. Let's not try to build policies on flawed _and_ hypothetical foundation.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then it goes into limbo. But a Stack Overflow Team page shouldn't be the place where important, public-facing information like that is kept, anyway. That's not the scope of Teams. If a project has only one contributor then it doesn't belong on a service for **Teams**. If the feature were called "Projects" or "Repos", then it'd be a different matter.

Comment: @LiveForever This is entirely independent of the voting activity suggestion.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, at two or more people.

Comment: @TylerH but how do you create a team page? Are you asking that one person submits the application, then it goes into a pool where one more person has to find it and sign-up before it can become active? Right now a member has to invite someone else for that person to become a member.

Comment: @TinyGiant From the post -  "creating a team is done by one person, but that team should remain hidden and/or "in limbo" until at least one other person accepts an invitation or requests to join it."

Comment: I didn't know there were even 8 people in the entire world (let alone on Meta) who didn't know that the word "team" referenced a plurality. Disturbing...

Comment: We perfectly understand that the word "team" references a plurality; however we also understand that in the real world, things can sometimes be a bit more complicated than that. `But a Stack Overflow Team page shouldn't be the place where important, public-facing information like that is kept, anyway.`  So you're saying the teams page should not contain any useful information, like a Q&A section would be? That's at odds with my understanding of the feature

Comment: @Pekka웃 A Team page on Stack Overflow is for people who are already on Stack Overflow to showcase their shared interest in something. It's not a repo, or a FAQ, or a code documentation page. And yes, the real world can be complicated, but when you are creating something from scratch, you have the benefit of being able to name it whatever you want and/or apply whatever rules you want, so "real life is complicated" isn't really a valid excuse here.

Comment: It may surprise you, but in fewer than 100% of developers in the world are on Stack Overflow. A team might have 10 members, only one of which has a Stack Overflow account. I see nothing wrong with allowing that one person to represent their team on Teams. The remaining nine developers may have *no interest* in starting an account just to join the Team, that doesn't mean the Team shouldn't exist.

Comment: It's also ridiculous to put a team back into "limbo" after it loses a member and goes back down to one person. What about all the valuable Q&A that's happened there, it just vanishes until the team gets another person? What if they hope to use their Team page to attract additional members? How can they do that if their public page is taken away?

Comment: @meagar "All the valuable Q&A" What Q&A? There's no such feature in Teams. Also note that my suggestion of "in limbo" is almost entirely undefined as of yet, so your concerns are, IMO, just FUD. Also, based on the name of the feature, I'd argue that it *does* mean a Team shouldn't be made if only one member *joins*.

Comment: @TylerH [Teams Q&A. It's a thing.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308601/the-goal-of-teams-our-follow-up-to-your-questions). Regardless, the **entire purpose of teams** is to showcase *some* kind of worth-while content. Your words were **hidden and/or "in limbo"**, and in a comment above when asked about what happens when a team drops to one user, you said: **"Then it goes into limbo."** So why would we spend time building up worth-while content on a Teams page, only to put it back to some state where it is, again, your words: "hidden and/or "in limbo".

Comment: @meagar Based on that post even the developers don't know what Teams Q&A is going to be yet. And to answer your question of why with another question: why give something a plural word for a name if it can be used by individuals?

Comment: @TylerH I will answer your question with another question: Who cares? Honestly. If literally the only reason you're proposing a fundamental change to he way the feature works is because of a semantic quibble with the name, **who cares**? Most photo sharing websites allow you to have an album with one photo. Should we abandon the word "album" for describing collections of photos unless you have two or more photos in the collection? No, because that would be confusing and pointless, and *nobody cares* that an album of one photo really isn't an "album".

Comment: I think that this question raises an important question -- just what *is* Teams? Because if it really is *Projects*, that's a very different feature.

Comment: @Linuxios That is very, *very* well discussed elsewhere. No, it's not projects. Yes, it is teams.

Comment: @meagar An album does not mean more than one, so that's not really a valid comparison. The reasons I'm proposing this incremental change (hardly a fundamental one) is to 1) safeguard against features that could help identify otherwise-hidden activity 2) cut down on repeated information (much of the info from a one-person project is better suited for their profile or an external site) and 3) effectively and pre-emptively reduce the noise-to-quality ratio by eliminating numerous Teams with only one person created for no good reason, like just as a "me too" measure.

Comment: @meagar If you are not interested in engaging with people who care, perhaps you should recuse yourself from moderating the site.

Comment: @TylerH I say "fundamental change" because this is a drastic change in how Teams would be created, and potentially could have a huge impact on the update of the feature. Even small barriers to entry can cause a *huge* drop-off in the adoption of a feature. And are we not engaging here? Because I feel like we're engaging. I think the fact that I am in here, voicing my disagreement, is a pretty strong indicator that I care.

Comment: @meagar We're engaging in this instance, but if your response is "**Who cares?**" (emphasis yours), well, that's not really a good attitude to have. Maybe you're just sending mixed signals.

Comment: `If you are not interested in engaging with people who care, perhaps you should recuse yourself from moderating the site.` Moderators have nothing to do with implementing feature requests aired on Meta. It's completely outside their scope. They are free to voice any criticism of suggestions, including "who cares about this".

Comment: @Pekka웃 As you can see this is now a bug report, but that aside, the topic of discussion is irrelevant; it's *how* moderators interact with users that matters. After all, we [hold them to higher standards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year) because they're supposed to represent the best of us. Any time a moderator makes a post or leaves a comment, it's as a moderator; there's no hiding that diamond. However, this discussion is getting off-topic.

Comment: I haven't seen any language from meagar here that is even remotely un-moderatorly. Your getting hung up on his "who cares" and suggesting it's somehow behaviour unbecoming a mod seems more than disingenuous - he's questioning the *basic premise of your feature request,* which is what Meta is for, not displaying a careless attitude towards you, or even the request itself.

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

Teams should allow for single player mode

---

At my organization we have a few guys who work on projects on their own, but by all forms and means, still get reported on as a single product or "team" if you will. This allows us to keep the same structure across the board when communicating, or planning or whatever else.

Transposing this to Stack Overflow...

If we wanted to get everyone on the SO teams train:

- They'd either have to be excluded
- Someone else would need to join for the sake of joining, or worse...
- We'd need to create a spoof profile to complete the team's creation process

None of the above options seem ideal, just for the sake of being correct according to the English language. Considering that developers are very liberal with their naming of things at the best of times, I'm sure this should be added to the exception list too.

**Just for fun
and because I wanted to use a picture...**

[image]

**an array of 1 is completely plausible.. albeit, somewhat lonely :P**

---

Comment: That fun picture is quite the reach just to justify the nomenclature. :-) Also I disagree that array can be a synonym of team unless the array is already quantified as 2 or more, because an array of 1 is *definitely* not a synonym of a team. Has your organization every considered using a better word?

Comment: @TylerH.. haha, yes. I agree. Erm, so we don't use the word teams on its own or in any formal docs. But when we talk about work streams or client projects, we normally reference it as a "Project Team". I'm not even sure of what to call it, so I'm not able to suggest a better name. Naming things is hard comes to mind, yet again.

Comment: Yellow highlighted text? Really? [This is Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZeYVIWz99I); we only use free-hand red circles. Get your head in the game.