# Can I ask a self-answered question that is very specific and won't be very helpful for many users?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I use Stack Overflow to document my problems and answer, but sometimes my problem is very specific and specific for my environment.

For example, my program was facing a *unable to activate windows store app* error.

This was because I attached the wrong lib file. So I want to remind myself that I need to use the static lib not the one that come with DLL (it has the same name).

My question is can I ask this kind of question and then provide an answer for it?

Comment: PSA/FYI: You do not need to use `<br>` tags to insert new lines in your posts.

Comment: You would be surprised how many people might have run into a similar or related issue. Sometimes just them reading your question and taking a poke around their own environment can help them solve a problem. Your issues might not be as specific and contextual as you think.

Comment: @yivi FYI is For Your Information, but what does "PSA" means ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSA is not helping here apparently)

Comment: FYI: PSA it's a TLA for "public service announcement".

Comment: But what does TLA mean? :P

Comment: @pHCito - **T**hree **L**etter **A**cronym

Comment: // , Here's my question: How much of the specificity would come from a rare technical situation, and how much would come from other factors? The usefulness of a solution to a technical problem is often in proportion to its rarity, because uncommon problems often take more effort to solve without a reference.

Comment: The key to this question type being on-topic is that enough information is in the question to actually identify the problem. If the you write a question and then use information not in the question (e.g. only available on your machine) in order to answer, then the question is off topic as either "no MCVE" or "not reproducible". For this question, the required information may be the output of some analysis tool showing that the files are DLLs instead of static versions of the libraries, or in some other manner show that the files you initially tried were DLLs.

Comment: The answer lies in whether the question will be of value to other users.  Here's an example of one of my self-answered Q&A's from 2014 that I think meets that criteria: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22175153/34806

Answer (score 26):

Stack Overflow is a public Q&A knowledgebase. It's not a place for you to post content that's private or otherwise not meant for anyone else to read.

I recommend a note-taking app, such as OneNote or Evernote. You could even add a comment to your source code instead if this issue is specific to one project.

Comment: SO Teams but without teammates... SOlo ?

Comment: @Quentin you are onto something, definitely I should have recommended **that** approach.

Comment: @QuentinHayot I [tried to point that out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316447/make-teams-require-multiple-people) once; there are a disturbing number of people here that don't realize a *team* requires multiple people.

Comment: I disagree. If someone wants to use Teams by himself, why not ? I can see the use case here. But maybe a "solo" less expensive plan would be nice.

Comment: @TylerH as someone once pointed out, although there's no 'I' in team there certainly is 'me'  ;)

Comment: @QuentinHayot My issue was with the nomenclature, but anyway one person wanting to use SO Teams is not a good use of SO Teams; they should use OneNote or Google Docs or code comments instead. Remember, the point of SO is a repository for all; the point of SO Teams is a repository for your *team*. If you don't need to share data with other people then there's no point in putting in the structure that SO/Teams is designed for.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Only if you totally change it so that it doesn't resemble its original form ;-) Same for Teams... it could be great for a mono-user repository, but only if you gut the feature set and change a bunch of stuff about it... otherwise it's one guy cleaning and maintaining a really fancy brick-and-mortar library that no one ever comes to visit.

Answer (score 19):

**Don't do that.** We have a close reason for that kind of question:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

These questions are inherently of very little use for anyone.

If you asked such a question, just delete it and move on. If you haven't and thinking about it, just refrain from doing so.

Writing a *good* self-answered question is particularly difficult. The objective of this type of question is not for users to write personal documentation, but to hopefully **share knowledge that other other users could benefit from**.

As such, the questions should be written trying to put yourself in the shoes of future visitors who are encountering a problem and haven't yet figured out the solution. And the circumstances of issue shouldn't be too localized, or no one else will benefit from the Q&A.

Comment: Thank you! got it now(I did not ask this kind of question yet). I wonder if there are any option to hide my question from everybody so it won't waste anybody time?

Comment: No. All non-deleted questions are public. Just use a different method to document this kind of thing.

Comment: Dispute `Writing a good self-answered question is particularly difficult.` Writing a good self-answered question is no more difficult than writing *any* good question. The fact self-answered Q&A are held to a higher standard is mainly due to some, usually misguided, notion of contributors' intentions.

Comment: @jpp: it's at least twice as hard as writing a good question that you don't self-answer, because not only the question, but the answer has to pass muster as well, and it's very easy for the author to produce an answer that helped *them* (obviously) but is a dubious hack or just devoid of useful context. Add to that that questions with answers (self-supplied or otherwise) get less eyeballs to begin with and yes, they're harder. There *is* some "how dare you presume to throw this out here answered and all, have my downvote" elitism going on as well, for sure, but it's not the only hurdle.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Misguided. There's this belief that self-answered is harder because you need to convince someone other than yourself it's worthwhile. But very few, if any, actually use SO as their personal notebook. There's this other belief that self-answers are rep-hunters and self-answered Q&A is only for canonicals. All a bit elitist, usual Meta fare.

Answer (score 7):

Along the lines of ouflak's comment, I'd say go ahead and post, with the question being something along the lines of "What can cause the error `unable to activate windows store app` when trying to submit an app to the Windows store?", and the answer being your findings about an incorrect .lib file.  (Assuming no such duplicate question already exists.)

If I were working on deploying a Windows Store app, and was facing down that error message with no idea what might be causing it, I'd certainly be happy to have such a StackOverflow Q&A come up as a Google search result for that error message.

Comment: +1, I think judgement is best left to the person who faced the problem. If they feel they need to make a note of it because the error message is unclear, *write the Q&A*. Let the community judge whether it's useful or not. The same error may also be caused by other problems. That's fine, others can also contribute answers and edge cases.

Comment: I agree with you: "hard to find", and "long tail" answers should be on SO. If it helps only one person, then SO purpose was fulfilled. If the competition had these answers, and not SO, then this is where I'd go shopping w/o looking back.