# Is it good/normal/expected that 12.5% of Team are community groups the rest are companies/projects?

Tags: discussion, old-teams

I had a theory that Teams are mostly being used by community groups, rather than Companies/Project. (I was wrong)

By community group, I mean some loose associations of people. E.g. [my hacker space has a team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/101/ucc). There are several "National" teams for people from a particular country. Another would be [SOPython](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/5/sopython).

Not, I am not suggestion one or the other is right in this post. Just presenting the facts.

What I want to know is the actual use of teams.

So just looking at teams with id between 84 and 201. And on each page of 12 teams there was one or two "community groups", which comes out at 12.5%

(Interestingly it seems like about 3% of teams are for various parts of Stack Overflow)

This was more a quick count than a proper investigation, but I figured I would share the results.

12.5% is what I would call a sizeable minority. It's not *most* people but it is a lot.

How can I do this sampling better? There are only 240 teams, so someone (possibly me, in a fit of insomnia) could do this better!

Comment: I think you possibly raise some interesting points here, but I'm a bit confused regarding what your actual question is. Perhaps it is, "What is the actual purpose of teams, and is that consistent with how they are currently being used?" A better title (one that is actually a question, rather than a statement of fact) would help a lot.

Comment: Changed. Though it definitely still vague, but that is kinda part of what the [discussion]  tag is about. More I have noticed this fact, and needed to share it with others.

Comment: ["Yes, the major motivator for teams is to integrate with careers and company pages and help developers find jobs"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/what-team-member-so-activity-should-we-gather-and-show-on-teams#comment304825_316326)

Comment: Hmm...just noticed this, mb we should have some political stack groups as well. How about Stack-OverTrump

Comment: Wah, I just knew about Teams. What does it do?

Comment: @justhalf Even the devs don't really know what Teams are for (besides Jobs integration), but [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316135/what-do-we-want-out-of-teams-and-how-could-we-make-it-work) and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316245/what-team-member-so-activity-should-we-gather-and-show-on-teams?lq=1) are where we're all trying to figure it out.

Comment: Currently I don't feel the need to be in a Team.

Answer (score -5):

**Is it good/normal/expected that 12.5% of Team are community groups the rest are companies/projects?**

Is it expected?

I didn't have any expectations, maybe StackOverflow had some but I do not know of them and guess they didn't share them. Answer: Unknown.

Is it normal?

We need to make some statistics. Make the same thing several times and if the ratio is always around 12.5% it would be normal, if it's wildly fluctuating, probably not. But there are no repetititions of this kind available as far as I know. Answer: Unknown.

Is it good?

Good for whom/in what sense? Currently the whole concept of Teams is still in beta and therefore I would argue that it is too early to judge it, especially while it seems still unknown if there is much benefit in Teams at all. They are finding out right now.

But assuming that there is something good in Teams I guess that then it's also good to have Community Teams and Company Teams but I would not speculate about an optimal ratio of the numbers of both since not enough is known about the impact of Teams on Q&A.

It might be that companies already working together as a team are naturally faster in adopting such a scheme while individual users need some time to team up with others, or maybe are more reluctant towards the concept of Teams.

To say that this ratio is not good I would probably ask for evidence that individuals not in a Team are severely disadvantaged. Until then I would tend to say that everything is good here.

And who knows, maybe that ratio changes in the future. Community driven Teams might catch up.